# IQKeyboardManager: keep multiple fields above keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, iqkeyboardmanager

I have a login form with 2 text fields. When you focus on the email field, the password field gets hidden by the keyboard. The return key does bring you to the password field, and tapping outside of a text field dismisses the keyboard, so it's not completely unusable, but it's not very intuitive either.

It would be much better if both fields were kept in view, above the keyboard. With the old version of IQKeyboardManager where was the concept of IQLayoutGuideConstraint which was maybe useful here, but that whole thing is gone now.

Any tips? This is not a tableview nor a scrollview.

[image]

Comment: I've been programming for iOS since 2009 and I've never heard of `IQKeyboardManager`. You should probably add an intro like "I'm using the `IQKeyboardManager` open source library (link) to manage scrolling my fields up to make room for the iOS software keyboard."

Comment: Well the question has the name of the library in the title and in the tags, so I was hoping to reach people who already know this library. Also because this library uses SO to answer questions :)

Comment: Just came across IQKeyboardManager and have same question. Any update?